# Plugin not found gradle errors in automated Android build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

Since adding Kotlin to our Android source, we're having intermittent failures on our automated builds. Most builds fail while the occaisonal build, say 1/10 perhaps, will succeed. The errors didn't occur before introducing Kotlin, and they don't occur when building locally on our dev machines- only on the build server.

When building via the command line (i.e. `gradlew assembleFlavour1Flavour2`) we get the following error: `Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found`. However, when we build from Android Studio (on the build server, the same Jenkins slave) we get a slightly different error: `Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found`. I have updated Android Studio (Through `File > Settings > System Settings > Updates`) and Kotlin (through `Android Studio > Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates`).

Our root `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Our application build.gradle, `app/build.gradle`, is (with sensetive business-specific parts redacted) as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.4.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    flavorDimensions "redacted", "redacted"

    productFlavors {

        ...(redacted)...
    }

    sourceSets {
        ...(redacted)...
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Set application name and filename
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        ...(redacted)...
    }

    //Add deploy tasks
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant -> 
        ...(redacted)...
    }

    //Add generate javadoc task
    project.tasks.create(name: "generateJavadoc", type:Javadoc) {
        ...(redacted)...
    }

    //Add clear javadoc task- ensures any previous javadoc files are removed first
    project.tasks.create(name: "deleteJavadocDeployment", type:Delete) {
        ...(redacted)...
    }

    //Add deploy javadoc task
    project.tasks.create(name: "deployJavadoc", type:Copy, dependsOn: ['deleteJavadocDeployment', 'generateJavadoc']) {
        ...(redacted)...
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.11.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.9.0'
}
```

For completeness, a full output from the command-line with --stacktrace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'redacted\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':ap
p'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:92)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$
2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(Project
ScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.
apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:192)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperat
ionScriptPlugin.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(De
faultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperat
ionScriptPlugin.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:39)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildSc
riptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.eva
luate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigur
e(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$100
(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$ConfigureP
roject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(De
faultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(L
ifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProjec
t.java:651)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProjec
t.java:133)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProje
ctEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(Task
PathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuil
dConfigurer.java:38)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ConfigureBuild.run(De
faultGradleLauncher.java:246)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(De
faultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.configureBuild(Defaul
tGradleLauncher.java:165)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(Default
GradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultG
radleLauncher.java:107)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBui
ldController.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBui
ldController.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultW
orkerLeaseService.java:152)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBu
ildController.java:100)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildC
ontroller.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(Exe
cuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildA
ctionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(
ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(R
unAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBu
ildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(De
faultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(Defaul
tBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(Run
AsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.ru
n(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProce
ssBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(Bu
ildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(Bu
ildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.ex
ecute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.ex
ecute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter
.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter
.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.
execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.
execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildAct
ionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildAct
ionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecu
ter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecu
ter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExe
cuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExe
cuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execu
te(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execu
te(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBu
ild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(
WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute
(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.
execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(Forw
ardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(For
wardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogA
ndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClien
t.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBu
ild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(Build
CommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(
DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.
run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(Daemon
StateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.
onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecu
torImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnabl
e.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin with id 'com.an
droid.application' not found.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPlu
ginManager.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.appl
yType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.acce
ss$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.ru
n(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.exec
ute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPlu
ginAware.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.jav
a:34)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_jesrcyvk01ha499dnctvfqjo.run(redacted\app\buil
d.gradle:1)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptR
unnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 93 more
```

`gradlew -v` reports the following version info:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-08-07 14:38:48 UTC
Revision:     941559e020f6c357ebb08d5c67acdb858a3defc2

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_152 (Oracle Corporation 25.152-b16)
OS:           Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 x86
```

According to the SDK Manager within Android Studio, we have the following SDK Platforms installed: `Android API 27 (rev. 1)`, `Android 8.0 (Oreo) (rev. 2)`, and the following SDK Tools installed: `Android SDK Build-Tools`, `Android Emulator (27.0.2)` (N.B. the machine is a VM, so the emulator doesn't work), `Android SDK Platform-Tools (27.0.1)`, `Android SDK Tools (26.1.1)`, `Android Support Repository (47.0.0)`, `Google Repository (58)`.

Android Studio version is 3.0, build no `AI-171.4443003`, SDK tools `26.1.1`, platform version API 27 revision 1. "ignored updates" is blank.

**Update:** Tried re-installing the Kotilin plugin and re-installing Android Studio altogether, neither worked. Tried creating a new default Android project with Kotilin on the server, and that has the exact same problem. So I'm thinking it must be a problem with the server configuration.

I've also found that I can create a new default project **without** Kotlin and it: builds in Android Studio, but **doesn't** build through the CLI.

Why are these errors occuring and what can I do to resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`. Correctly it should be:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no luck. I tried putting it alongside the Fabric.io maven include but the exact same error occurred, and I tried replacing the Fabric.io maven with it but then I get errors that `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1` could not be found.

Comment: Also tried adding to to both the buildscript{} and allprojects {} segments with the same results. Missing com.android :(